# Reset ROW_NUMBER() after break

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following SQL Server query on which i'm having some trouble using ROW_NUMBER().

```
Select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by R.DriverName, CASE WHEN Sum(R.Points) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Order By E.EventDate ASC) As 'RowID',
    CASE WHEN Sum(R.Points) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As 'PointsId',
    R.DriverName,
    R.EventID,
    Format(E.EventDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as 'Event Date'
From Races R
    Inner Join Events E
        On E.EventID = R.EventID
Where R.SeriesID Like 'FOE' And E.EventType Like 'R' And R.DriverName Like 'Lucas di Grassi'
Group By R.DriverName, R.EventID, E.EventDate
Order By E.EventDate
```

And get the following result:

[image: result]

I want that after each 0 on PointsId Column, the RowID resets to 1 and adds up again until the next 0.

Can anyone help?

Thank you,
Vítor

Answer (score 3):

You need nested Analytic Functions:

```
Select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by R.DriverName, grp Order By E.EventDate ASC) As 'RowID',
...
from
 (
    Select
        -- assign a number to each group of rows
        SUM(CASE WHEN Sum(R.Points) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        OVER (Partition by R.DriverName
              Order By E.EventDate ASC) As grp,
...
    From Races R
        Inner Join Events E
            On E.EventID = R.EventID
    Where R.SeriesID Like 'FOE' And E.EventType Like 'R' And R.DriverName Like 'Lucas di Grassi'
    Group By R.DriverName, R.EventID, E.EventDate
 ) as dt
Order By E.EventDate
```